# Java regex for String containing decimals seperated by comma

Tags: java, regex

I am making Java app where user enters a decimal seperated by comma like: -343.123,0.32 or 3,-321 used for Latitude and Longitude like:
Latitude,Longitude where both Latitude and Longitude are `double`

Valid string: `43,-23.123` or `32.312,32.33`

I have tried this regex, but it is not working:

```
str.matches("^[-0-9.0-9][,][-0-9.0-9]$")
```

Comment: which output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sloppy match (allows multiple - and . characters):

```
"^[-+0-9.]+,[-+0-9.]+$"
```

A more exact one:

```
"^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*,[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$"
```

Special characters

```
? : zero or more matches of preceding
+ : one or more matches of preceding (except when in character set)
* : zero or more matches of preceding
```

Hope that helps. Change the match character on the integer portion of the numbers to * if you expect lat/long without integer (very unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about which lat or long is valid with negative values, but
this is a good regex for double's without the exponent.

`^\s*([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))\s*,\s*([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))\s*$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      [+-]? 
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* , \s* 
 (                             # (2 start)
      [+-]? 
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )                             # (2 end)
 \s* 
 $
```